# Emberjs Delete url goes without id

Tags: api, rest, ember.js, playframework-2.0

i have this task creator with emberjs and an API made in scala with play framework.

When I click the delete button i go to the taskController to do this:

```
Tasks.TaskController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    deleteTask: function(){
       var task = this.get('model');        
       task.deleteRecord();
       task.get('store').commit();
    }
});
```

And it sends a DELETE request to

```
http://localhost:9000/api/tasks
```

but it doesn't put the id in the end like

```
http://localhost:9000/api/tasks/:id
```

I even though of adding a route in the API to get a JSON and delete from there, but the commit doesn't send anything.

in the router.js i have something like this

```
Tasks.Router.map(function() {
    this.resource('tasks', {path: '/'}, function(){
        this.route('new');
        this.resource('task', {path: '/:_id'}, function(){
            this.route('edit', {path : '/:_id'});
            this.route('deleteTask', {path : '/cenas/:_id'});
            this.route('delete', {path : '/cenas/:_id'});
        });
        this.route('deleteTask', {path : '/cenas/:_id'});
        this.route('delete', {path : '/cenas/:_id'});
    });
});
```

The model

```
Tasks.Task = DS.Model.extend({
    _id: DS.attr('string'),
    idUser: DS.attr('string'),
    label: DS.attr('string'),
    date: DS.attr('date')
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you mapped _id as your primaryKey?

```
 App.Adapter.map('App.Person', {
    primaryKey: '_id'
  });
```

https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/packages/ember-data/lib/system/serializer.js#L79

Outside of that missing piece things should work with your initial code block. You don't need to define a delete route as your application is never transitioning to an actual delete route.